# colorbox plugin: full screen

Tags: jquery, iframe, fullscreen, colorbox

I'm displaying a URL in a colorbox iframe. Something along the lines of :

```
$.colorbox({href: url, open:true, iframe: true,  fastIframe:false, width:"1024px", height: "768px", scrolling: false,overlayClose: false,closeButton: false});
```

I would like the colorbox to go full screen (like a full screen YouTube video). I'm not sure how to do this. Setting width:"100%" height:"100%" only makes the colorbox occupy the full view port.

any ideas?